# Is instance variables in rails are reset every page refreshed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if instance variable are reset everytime I refresh the page ?

And is it possible to not reset it ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you mean controller instance variables: yes, they are, no, not's not possible. What are you trying to achieve anyway? Maybe there's some other way to do it?

Comment: I want to set a default variable to my @vendor variable in ApplicationController and i want to modify it using an api call in my react side. I can set it with my api call but if i refresh my page the 'before filter set_default_vendor' reset this variable..

Comment: Are you OK modifying the constant in React every page load? If so just assign the default variable to a constant and use that

Comment: No I don't want to have this variable in client-side

Comment: "And is it possible to not reset it ?" - you can persist information between requests by saving it in the database, the session or memory or disk based storage. It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Rephrase the question and ask about that problem you are trying to solve. Not what you think is the solution.